# Архивация определённых типов файлов по шаблону

Tags: linux, tar

Нужно архивировать файлы определённого формата.

Вот так я пытаюсь это сделать:

```
tar -czvf example.tar.gz -C /path/to/exclude/ /path/to/files/*.file -T /path/files_list
tar -czvf example2.tar.gz -C /path/to/exclude2/ /path/to/files/*.file2 -T /path/files_list
```

Но получаю ошибку:

```
tar: /path/to/files/*.file: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
```

Пробовал добавить патерны в /path/files_list, но они там не работают.
Можно ли как-то использовать шаблоны в списке файлов ?

Comment: Что-то я не понимаю смысл ключа, которые вы записали в командной строке. Вот ключ -С оозначает "change to directory DIR". И причём тут */path/to/exclude/* ?! А если Вы действительно переходите в этот каталог, то зачем тогда */path/to/files/*.file* ?! И как явный список файлов может быть совмещён с файловой маской?

Comment: Параметр -C нужен чтоб убрать из пути все лишнее.
Про остальное не совсем понял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил задачу так:

```
for dir in path1 path2; do
    cd /home/$dir/path
    tar -czf ~/archive.tar.gz $(cat /path/to/include_filelist_patterns) -X /path/to/exclude_filelist -T /path/to/include_filelist --ignore-failed-read
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Делаю так

```
find ./source/77TR_2/ -iname '*.DBF' | tar czf 77TR_2-`date +%F`.tar.gz --files-from=-
```

Пример из реальной жизни. Сохранение файлов в архив со снапшота файловой системы

```
root@srv2:~# cat /usr/local/bin/backup-base.sh
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

lvcreate -L1G -s -n back-bases /dev/lghost/bases
mkdir -p /backup/source
mount -o ro,offset=1048576 /dev/lghost/back-bases /backup/source
cd /backup/
find ./source/77TR_1/ -iname '*.DBF' | tar czf 77TR_1-`date +%F`.tar.gz --files-from=-
find ./source/77TR_2/ -iname '*.DBF' | tar czf 77TR_2-`date +%F`.tar.gz --files-from=-
umount /backup/source
lvremove -f /dev/lghost/back-bases
```

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, как-то так:

```
cd /path/to/files/
ls *.file > files_list
tar -czvf example.tar.gz -T files_list
```

Если это действительно нужно, то можете добавить ключ *-X /path/to/exclude/*

Comment: Спасибо за вариант.
Но он мне не совсем подходит. 
Так как у меня много разных архивов создается.
И список файлов 1 для всех (меняется только часть пути)